# pattern matching of variant tag in OCaml

Tags: design-patterns, pattern-matching, ocaml, variant

I have the following OCaml substitution function.

```
let rec subst x a f =                                                                                                                                    
    match f with                                                                                                                                           
    | Var s -> if s = x then a else Var s                                                                                                                 
    | Implies (f1, f2) -> Implies (subst x a f1, subst x a f2)                                                                                            
    | And (f1, f2) -> And (subst x a f1, subst x a f2)                                                                                                     
    | Or (f1, f2) -> Or (subst x a f1, subst x a f2)                                                                                                                                                                                   
    | True | False as e -> e
```

Some cases are almost identical and I'm wondering if there's a way to factorize them somehow.

Ideally, I'm thinking of a construct of the form:

```
match f with
| tag (f1, f2) -> tag (subst x a f1, subst x a f2)
| ...
```

that would match all my binary operations.

An other use case would be in a to_string function where we could have:

```
match f with
| tag (f1, f2) -> print_string ((tag_to_string tag) ^ ...  )
| ...
```

I know this isn't possible in OCaml, but is there a pattern or a language construct that goes in that direction?

Comment: Although not implemented in Ocaml, You might want to read [that blog post](http://gallium.inria.fr/blog/pattern-synonyms-as-expressions) about an hypothetical feature similar to what you describe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, but you can create one `Binop` constructor that you could use more easily.
So your type definition would become something like:

```
type binop = Implies | And | Or
type t =
  | Var of string
  | Binop of binop * t * t
  | True | False
```

Then your function could be:

```
let rec subst x a f =
  match f with
  | Var s -> if s = x then a else f
  | Binop (b, f1, f2) -> Binop (b, subst x a f1, subst x a f2)
  | True | False -> f
```

Note that this makes `Binop` use one more word than your version, which is (at most times) a good price to pay for less codelines.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you can't bind constructor. If you find yourself tired from this, you can write mapper/folder classes, so that you don't need to repeat yourself.

For example, in mine project substitution [function](https://github.com/BinaryAnalysisPlatform/bap/blob/master/lib/bap_types/bap_helpers.ml#L190)  looks like this (for much more complex language)

```
let substitute x y = (object inherit mapper
  method! map_exp z = if Exp.(x = z) then y else z
end)#run
```

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: I am more familiar with Haskell than Ocaml, so I may not be doing things in the most idiomatic way)

I don't know of a general way (besides some sort of macro) to solve this problem, but a type of encoding that I have learned and find helpful is the following:

```
type t =
  | Var of t
  | Implies of t * t
  | And of t * t
  | Or of t * t
  | True
  | False

let apply_t var implies and_t or_t true_t false_t = function
  | Var s -> var s
  | Implies (a, b) -> implies a b
  | And (a, b) -> and_t a b
  | Or (a, b) -> or_t a b
  | True -> true_t
  | False -> false_t
```

This should help the definition of some functions and an abstract use of the type. In this case, it only results in less code if you have to define more of these kinds of functions. Nevertheless, it may give you some ideas. With a few more helpers, we can see how a function like `subst` could easily be implemented

```
(* Ocaml constructors behave oddly *)
let impliest (a, b) = Implies (a, b)
let andt (a, b) = And (a, b)
let ort (a, b) = Or (a, b)

let rec subst x a =
  let varf s = if s = x then a else Var s in
  let bin_subst tag f1 f2 = tag (subst x a f1, subst x a f2) in
  apply_t varf (bin_subst impliest) (bin_subst andt) (bin_subst ort) True False
```

Another possibility that probably fits some use cases better is to encode both `True` and `False` as a single parameter taking the value as a parameter in the `apply_t` function.

Comment: What you call "oddly" is that ctors in ML languages are not functional, they're just special literals. It's true that once you start thinking about their types, you realise their functional nature and feel that there something seemingly missing there in ML, but functions in ML and Haskell cannot be shown, whereas ctors may, so wouldn't you say that functions are odd?

Comment: My point is that ctors are at a "junction" point between algebraic and functional values, and as such they could be adapted to fit either group in a language, but they'll always be odd. I think that's pretty much the essence of OP's question.

Comment: That's a good explanation of their behaviour. Thank you. What actually got in my way when writing this answer is that up until writing it, I thought that constructors took tuples as parameters, but, as you said, they are just special literals. So it's just a case of me being unfamiliar with some parts of the language. I'm actually more inclined to use Ocaml than Haskell for a new project, so don't take this as me bashing Ocaml.

Comment: I'm not taking this as bashing ocaml: "odd" is when things don't seem normal, and normality is (subjectively) a notion built through experience. I wanted to give you my point of view as an OCamler who thought that Haskell ctors are odd, at first :)

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach would be to write a nested function just above your match expression, but you have to modify your variant:

```
type t =
  | Var of t
  | Implies of (t * t) (* NOTE the parens around the arguments *)
  | And of (t * t)
  | Or of (t * t)
  | True
  | False

let rec subst x a f =
  let g f1 f2 = (subst x a f1, subst x a f2) in
  match f with
  | Var s -> if s = x then a else Var s
  | Implies (f1, f2) -> Implies (g f1 f2)
  | And (f1, f2) -> And (g f1 f2)
  | Or (f1, f2) -> Or (g f1 f2)
  | True | False as e -> e
```

There is some code duplication so it doesn't scale as well as PatJ's, but it's also clearer in some sense since you only have three binary operations.

Regarding your tag idea, I don't believe there is a way to bind constructors based on the number of arguments. For details, see http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/patterns.html

Comment: I believe your suggestion is incorrect. The constructor Or expects two arguments (and not a binary tuple value such as the one returned by g).

Comment: Thanks Nemo! Fixed it.

Comment: and "(t, t)" should be "(t * t)" :)

Comment: Thanks again. That's the last time I post without compiling/testing.